# Using the config file in Laravel Schedule Job

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler

Can I load the config file when the scheduling job starts?

I tried to use a local variable `customerName` in Schedule Class and it already defined in the Config folder as named `customerInfo`.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Config;

class Checkout extends Command
{
   ***
   public function handle()
   { 
      ***

      $customerName = Config::get('customerInfo.customer_name'); //test code
      \Log::info($customerName); // for error check in log file

      ***
   }

}
```

but it was not worked.

Do I have to declare it in the constructor
or have to use `'\'` as `'\Config'` even if already declared alias as `use Config;`?

What is the best simple solution to use custom variable in Config when schedule job is running start?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not defined in what namespace PHP can find the `Config` class.

You need to either include the `Config` facade in your usings on top of the class:

```
use Config;
```

Or use [the config helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-config):

```
config('customerInfo.customer_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

`config()` helper or `Config` Facade is used to get the values from `config` dir.

Create a new file in config folder with name `customerInfo`.

```
return [
   'customer_name' => 'A name'
];
```

Now you can access the name

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Checkout extends Command
{
   ***
   public function handle()
   { 
      ***

      $customerName = Config::get('customerInfo.customer_name'); //test code
      \Log::info($customerName); // for error check in log file

      ***
   }

}
```